# Arc length meaning

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, parametric, projectile-motion

I am currently studying about Parametric integration and very confuse about the arc length meaning.

In my understanding, the arc length is the total length that an object traveled along a curve in a given interval, in other words the length of the curve in that interval.
Let say an object travels on a circle motion with  the parametric equations.

$x=3\cos(3t)$.   $y=\sin(3t)$

in the interval $[0,2\pi]$

using the formula for arc length which is $ L= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt(y’^2+x’^2)dx$
the answer is $18\pi$ which meets my understanding that arc length is the whole distance travelled so 3 times around  the circle.

However if we given the parametric curve
$x=\sin^2(t)$  $y=\cos^2(t)$  for the interval $[0,3\pi]$

although the object should be going 6 times back and fourth between 2 points however when using L formula with limits 0 and $3\pi$ the answer is different from when we integrate in the interval $[0,\pi/2]$ and then multiply by 6, so why in this case the arc length formula is not working if we integrate over the full interval $[0,3\pi]$ as I thought that it would give us the total distance without changing the limits.

Also is my understanding correct that the formula would give the total distance traveled and not the displacement

Comment: You need to be careful with second integration. It is zero at endpoints but not in between.

Comment: What you described as a parametric circle is actually an ellipse.   Furthermore the path parameterized by your second pair of equations (sine and cosine squared) is a straight line segment.

Comment: What makes it zero, I really hope to understand how this formula works @cosmo5

Comment: Yes the second is a line but it the interval it is going between 2 points 6 times so why when we just integrate it is not giving the write answer, is it because the curve is not smooth.

Comment: Different paths can have different lengths.

Comment: In the first case it's not $18 \pi$, it's an elliptic integral.

Comment: Si you mean arc length is a displacement  and doesn’t calculate the total distance travelled?

Comment: You should show us your computation so that we can pinpoint your mistake.

Comment: My bet is that you did not consider an absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{4\sin^2t\cos^2x+4\cos^2t\sin^2t}\,dt=\sqrt2\int_0^{\pi/2}|\sin 2t|\,dt.$$
and using periodicity and symmetry,
$$\int_0^{3\pi}|\sin 2t|\,dx=3\int_0^{\pi}|\sin 2t|\,dx=6\int_0^{\pi/2}|\sin 2t|\,dt.$$

[image]

Comment: But in the first place how we find that interval [0,pi/2] we only given [0,3pi]
Also doing a small table we have the curve going just between (0,1) and (1,0) why it is different in your graph?

Comment: Sorry the equations are given in parametric forms not y with respect to x

Comment: @Rosa: sorry for introducing confusion by using $x$ instead of $t$. The plot is $s$ as a function of $t$. But you did not address my comments, this is a pity.

Comment: @Rosa: sorry for introducing confusion by using $x$ instead of $t$. The plot is the derivative of $s$ as a function of $t$. But you did not address my comments, this is a pity.